# Error accessing NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE field from org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle

Tags: java, apache, tostring

I am working with a java project using maven. It gives the compile time error, symbol not found. Following are relevant lines of code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
...
return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE);
```

Deleting the style parameter gets away with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using an older version of commons lang. The `ToStringStyle.NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE` property is available since [version 3.4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle.html#NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE). Try updating the dependency in your `pom.xml` to a version >= 3.4.